# How to optimize a non-linear objective function with non-linear constraints in R?

Tags: r, optimization

Say, there is a non-linear objective function :

```
Z= a1 + b1 * ln(x1) + a2 + b2 *ln(x2)  with the objective of maximizing Z
```

subject to the following constraints-

```
x1 + x2 + x3 >=R1
x1 + x2 + x3 <=R2
a1 + b1 * ln(x1) >=R3
```

How can the objective function be optimized in R? Tried using 'Rsolnp' package available in R, however not sure how to frame the constraints and the objective function that will be given to the function 'solnp' in the package.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is `x3` a constant?

Comment: x1,x2 and x3 are decision variables

Comment: asked because it does not appear in the objective function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you may want to use other algorithms like `NLOPT_LD_MMA` with jacobian specified):

```
library(nloptr)
a1 <- b1 <- 1
a2 <- b2 <- 1
R1 <- R2 <- 1
R3 <- 25

eval_f1 <- function( x, a1, b1, a2, b2, R1, R2, R3){ 
  return(-a1 - b1 * log(x[1]) - a2 - b2 *log(x[2])) # maximize
}


eval_g1 <- function( x, a1, b1, a2, b2, R1, R2, R3) {
  return(rbind(x[1] + x[2] + x[3] - R1,
               -x[1] - x[2] - x[3] + R2,
               R3 - a1 - b1*log(x[1])))
}

nloptr(x0=c(1,1,1), 
        eval_f=eval_f1, 
        lb = c(1,1,1), 
        ub = c(5,5,5), 
        eval_g_ineq = eval_g1, 
        opts = list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA"),
        a1 = a1,
        b1 = b1,
        a2 = a2,
        b2 = b2,
        R1 = R1,
        R2 = R2,
        R3 = R3)

#Call:
#nloptr(x0 = c(1, 1, 1), eval_f = eval_f1, lb = c(1, 1, 1), ub = c(5, 
#    5, 5), eval_g_ineq = eval_g1, opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_COBYLA"),     
#a1 = a1, b1 = b1, a2 = a2, b2 = b2, R1 = R1, R2 = R2, R3 = R3)


#Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.0 

#NLopt solver status: 5 ( NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because #maxeval (above) was reached. )

#Number of Iterations....: 100 
#Termination conditions:  relative x-tolerance = 1e-04 (DEFAULT) 
#Number of inequality constraints:  3 
#Number of equality constraints:    0 
#Current value of objective function:  -5.08783644210816 
#Current value of controls: 5 4.385916 2.550764
```